# What are my options to run a WFS with Geoserver and IIS?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, openlayers, fme-form, iis

I want to set up a **WFS** using **Geoserver** within **Jetty** servlet container. The server is running **Windows Server 2008 R2** and is using **IIS** primarily. Not opening another port is preferable. Apparently one solution could be utilizing **IIS**’s  Url-Rewriting to make **Geoserver** (or the **WFS**) accessible. The **WFS** should only be available for authenticated users – I have to use **digest**-encryption.

When **WFS** is working there are basically two uses cases:

1. **FME**-Script should use the **WFS** to retrieve data to process
2. web-app monitoring the data (**Openlayers 3**)

In the first case the access should not be the problem. I am a bit worried regarding the authentication. Basically **FME** can handle **digest**-encryption, but can the url-rewriting possibly cause problems? Can anyone share experiences?
In the second case I do not know if it is even possible. The web-application is going to be on a completely different server, so the url rewriting cannot serve as a (reverse) proxy. I might use a proxy here or use cross domain access. Is there any other option? How can I handle the authentication – is it even possible?

Another thing that comes into my mind is: Do cookies/session-object still work, or must **Geoserver** run through the whole authentication chain again for every request?

Comment: Authentication is generally handled by the web server, so you shouldn't have to worry about GeoServer handling the authentication if you proxy (or redirect) the service.  IIS can be on a different server from GeoServer and still handle the proxying/redirection.  Did you look at ISAPI redirector (https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html)